# How to change foreground color in kivymd's MdTextField?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField

class Mywidget(BoxLayout):
       pass
class Myapp(MdApp):
       def build(self):
             return Mywidget()
Myapp().run()
```

Kv file:-->myapp.kv

```
<Mywidget>
     orientation:"horizontal"
     MDTextField:
          halign:"center"
          valign:"center"
          hint_text:"Enter your name"
          foreground_color:1,1,0,1
```

But textfield's foreground color not change.How can I change it.I checked it's solution on internet but nothing happen.

Answer (score 1):

```
MDTextField:
    text_color_normal: 1,0,1,1
```

You may also want to change 'text_color_focus'.

Answer (score 0):

```
MDTextField
    line_color_focus: 1, 0, 1, 1
```

https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/text-field/index.html#color-mode